# Flex : Unable to rotate header text in Datagrid

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I'm having trouble in rotating the header text in my datagrid. I don't know understand the reason why its failing.Can someone help?

Datagrid column AS3 code:

```
                dgc=new DataGridColumn();
                dgc.dataField=columnName.gene;
                dgc.labelFunction=gridLabelFunction
                dgc.headerText=columnName.gene;
                //dgc.headerWordWrap=true;
                dgc.headerRenderer=new ClassFactory(VDGHeader);
                dgc.width=20;
                _datagridColumnsArray.push(dgc);
```

Please find my Header Renderer component below

```
        import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
        import mx.managers.SystemManager;

        [Bindable] private var text:String;
        [Bindable] private var src:String;

        override public function set data(value:Object):void{
            var col:DataGridColumn = value as DataGridColumn;
            text = col.headerText;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<mx:Label id="txtLbl" text="{text}" rotation="10" width="100%" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually doesn't have anything to do with column headers.

To rotate text in Flex you must embed the font. Otherwise the rotation will simply be ignored.

See [Adobe's docs on Embedding Fonts](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html)

Comment: I tried embedding my fonts and it didnt work. Is there anything wrong in the way I embedded the font? [Embed(source='/Library/Fonts/Tahoma Bold.ttf', fontName='myTahoma', mimeType='application/x-font')] 
   public var myTahoma:Class;

Comment: Hmm, you embedded your font but did you set the font of the column header (your label in this case) to be this embedded font?

Comment: Yes,I did. But after setting the font, I'm unable to see the headertext when rotation is set to 0.<mx:Label id="txtLbl" text="{text}" fontFamily="myTahoma" rotation="0" width="100%" />

Comment: Maybe best to post a complete mxml code snippet for others to try out.

Comment: As mentioned in the Adobe docs, I embedded the font in @font-face and then used the fontFamily name in the Label.It works perfectly.Appreciate your help.